# How to Impersonate Local Service account to Read remote registry

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an issue in the application while accessing the permission of the following registry key `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurePipeServers\winreg`

I am using WMI `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey` method to read the registry. If the registry key is having Both Administrator and Local service Permission, the code will retrieve all the permissions of the registry key. But if the Local service permission is removed from the Registry key the code will give the following error

> System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.
>      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
>      at ClassLibrary1.Class4.Main(String[] args)
>
> The Zone of the assembly that failed was:  MyComputer

When I searched on google, I found that to read that registry permission we required the following permissions

"Administrators" -  "Full Control"
"Local Service"  -  "Read"

I need to impersonate the Local Service permission from my C#.net application

How can I impersonate?